# What would the night sky look like from Luna (Earth's moon)?

Tags: moons, earth, astronomy

> Prima walked out to the observatory's main deck. There, as she had expected, Secunda was sitting in the grass, looking up at the stars.
>
> "Pretty, isn't it?" said Secunda, as she craned her neck backwards to look at her sister. "You can see everything tonight."
>
> "Everything?" replied Prima. Slowly wading through the grass, she glanced up and was instantly spellbound by the celestial garden of steady pinpricks of light, white and yellow and blue and red, smeared into blooming radiant petals by the thick observatory dome.
>
> "Everything," whispered Secunda. "Well," she added, "except for Terra, I suppose." She stood, stretched, sighed, and turned to her starry-eyed sister. "Hey," she said, "I want you to follow me. There's a telescope over there that has a lens outside the dome. I bet we can see Mars from here."
>
> Prima frowned slightly. "Really? Where is Mars from here, anyway?"

---

Suppose that Prima and Secunda are from our Earth, only a few centuries in the future. **Could Mars be visible from Luna's night sky? What else would be visible? Would it be normal for Terra to not appear at night?**

I know that, at a minimum, Luna's lack of atmosphere would mean that stars don't twinkle. I suspect that the Milky Way is apparent sometimes, and that the sky's view changes as Terra orbits Sol, so that the seasonal constellations are either similar or analogous in scheduling.

---

Edit: Thank you to all contributors. I've tried to upvote every helpful response, and will be thinking of tidal locking and thin atmosphere quite a bit now. I need the practice, so have some more:

> "Got it! Aw, Jupiter's not as big as I had hoped," whined Secunda, pulling her face away from the goggles. The optical tube trailing the goggles, large and padded, made a sympathetic groan as it sagged slightly.
>
> "What‽ No way, let me see already," Prima said as she groped for the goggles in her sister's hands.
>
> "Okay," said Secunda. Prima's hands met hers on the goggles. She stepped towards Prima, and helped orient the optical tube to a position approaching stability. Prima pressed her face to the goggles, while Secunda giggled quietly.
>
> Prima frowned, then jerked up from the goggles and glared at her sister. "You cheat! That's a photograph, isn't it? That's not real!" she protested, before breaking out into giggles herself. "You're such a joker sometimes," she snorted between laughs.
>
> Secunda frowned. "No, I didn't," she started, then gripped the goggles harder and pushed them back into her sister's face. "Look carefully. Do you see it?"
>
> Prima stared closely at the beautiful storm-ridden gaseous orb for a few moments, then gasped, "It's…moving? Crawling? It's alive! I can only barely see it, but it's moving somehow. Rotating?"
>
> Both sisters were quiet for a moment. Then Secunda poked Prima. "C'mon, it's my turn again!" she said.

Comment: Earth will be visible every night or never visible depending on the side of the moon you are on because 1 side always face earth and the other never does. Although earth will have phases but even the night side of the Earth should be visible from artificial lighting.

Comment: Hi Corbin. I edited your question slightly to try to (in my opinion) make the title more clear and improve the formatting to make it more readable. Feel free to [edit] further, or even roll back, if you disagree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At this moment? According to NASA/JPL and their simulator  at http://space.jpl.nasa.gov/ , something like

[image: mars from moon]

Comment: How come Sun is so much smaller compared to earth? Is that strictly the effect of no atmosphere?

Comment: @DRF - think the image is due to the options I chose, which included a 120 degree FOV

Comment: @DRF The sun in the sky is going to take up about 1/2 of a degree, from either the Earth or the moon. (And from the moon, Earth takes up 2 degrees.) But his ivanivan's answer about the field of view explains the image above.

Comment: @BrettFromLA - what FOV in degrees would give a realistic view of what the human eye would see?  I know I can see more than 120 degrees, but that was the max value available in the option.

Comment: @ivanivan That's a good question.  I don't know. I think we're used to standard photographs from cameras and phones, without telephoto or wide angle lenses, and I would guess that FOV is ... 90 degrees?

Comment: @DRF People always tend to overestimate the angular size of the sun and the moon. It's a well-known optical illusion.

Answer (score 7):

Because the moon is relatively close to Earth the night sky will be relatively similar. The two big differences are the lack of an atmosphere and a big planet in the sky instead of a moon.

Whether the earth is visible on the moon is dependant on where on the moon you are. The moon is tidally locked to the Earth so the same side will always be facing the Earth. From the near side of the moon the [earth is always visible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NASA-Apollo8-Dec24-Earthrise.jpg).

Without an atmosphere there will be less light pollution and twinkling.

Comment: Would it be safe to say there would be **no** light pollution or twinkling? There's nothing for light to bounce off (except possible dust from impacts or activities), and nothing to diffract light from stars.

Comment: The earth is many times brighter than the moon, and there is dust and traces of gasses to scatter light, so there will be light pollution . However,  there will be no twinkling,

Comment: Suggesting this minor edit for clarity: _“From the near side of the moon the earth is always visible, **and always fixed at the same location in Luna's sky**.”_

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Not quite fixed, there is some Libration.

Comment: @BrettFromLA probably a lot less light pollution but electrically charged dust is an issue on the moon in both daylight and at night.  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/what-is-the-average-electrical-charge-on-the-lunar-surface

Comment: @BrettFromLA -, earthshine will be brighter than moonshine, so even without earth/moon based light sources polluting you'll still loose those stars on the edge of visible brightness

Answer (score 5):

Could Mars be visible from Luna’s night sky? Yes depending on the time of year and the hour of the day, as on earth.
Would it be normal for Terra to appear at night? From the far side of Luna no never, from the near side of Luna yes always as Luna is tidally locked to Terra it rotates once per month so always shows the same face to Terra.

Answer (score 4):

**Generally speaking, you can see the same stars from the moon as you can from the Earth, but there are some issues:**

1) The moon is [tidal locked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) to the earth, which means the same face ***always*** faces the earth.  If you are on the far side of the moon, you will always see stars in the same manner as if you were standing on the Earth.  If you are on the near side of the moon, you will always be looking past the Earth, which means the Earth will block almost everything (if not everything) in the sky.

Also, if you are on the far side of the moon, you will experience a long day ([~13.5 days](https://www.space.com/24871-does-the-moon-rotate.html)), and a long night (also ~13.5 days).  If you live on the near-side of the moon, you will experience those same long days and nights, but you will also have periods of reflected light from the earth (full moon) and eclipsed light from the earth (new moon).  You need only look at a [lunar phases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_phase) to see what "daylight" is on the near face.

> This is a big deal as it means a substantial number of stars won't be visible either because the sun is in your eyes or the Earth is blocking the view.

2) The moon's orbit is not on the same orbital plane as the Earth (see pic, below).  This means the stars visible on Earth at a particular time won't be the same stars visible to the moon at that same time.  (What do I mean by this?  If it were the middle of the night and the moon were directly overhead, then someone standing on the Earth's equator will see a slightly different star field than someone standing on the moon's equator.)

[image]

3) The moon wobbles something awful (see pic below and [relevant discussion on Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/9937/shouldnt-all-moon-orbits-be-inherently-unstable)).  This will also affect what stars are visible at a given moment compared to the same moment on Earth.

[image]

Comment: *"Earth will block almost everything (if not everything) in the sky":* The Earth is not that big in the moon sky. See the many many [pictures made by the astronauts of the Apollo missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NASA-Apollo8-Dec24-Earthrise.jpg); it is about 4 times as large as the Moon is on Earth's sky. *"The moon wobbles something awful":* only for suitably chosen values of "awful"; its movement is regular enough to allow it to be used to [determine longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_distance_(navigation)) with remarkable precision.

Comment: What, exactly, is that second image meant to be showing/demonstrating?

Comment: @AlexP, that's a great point.  The Earth would only reduce the star field by a minor amount.  Thanks!

Comment: @MozerShmozer, the moon wobbles in its orbit.  It comes from a relevant [question on astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/9937/shouldnt-all-moon-orbits-be-inherently-unstable) (which I wasn't bright enough to include in the answer... problem solved.)

Comment: *"This means the stars visible on Earth at a particular time won't be the same stars visible to the moon at that same time":* It may surprise you, but the stars visible from Earth at a given time are not the same in Bucharest and Timbuktu... For any given time and place on the Moon there is a place on Earth where the exact same stars are visible at the same time (unless they are not visible because of the sunlight washing them out during dayime).

Comment: @AlexP, I didn't realize I needed to be so specific.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Adding to @AlexP's initial comment, it's also worth keeping in mind that absent an atmosphere, there is nothing to spread light out in the sky. So the Sun and the Earth are likely to be very bright, and the ground (assuming you're on the daylight side of the Moon) will be awfully bright, but other than that, the sky will be essentially pitch black. If you look away from any of these three bright objects for long enough to allow your eyes to adapt to the lower light levels, the view of the sky will be, pardon the pun, outright stellar.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, That's true, but only so long as the sun is not within your peripheral vision.  You would need to turn away far enough that the sun is entirely behind you or have something (e.g., your space suit helmet) that blocks the sun from your periphery.  I'm merely pointing out interesting aspects of the relationship.  The OP can decide whether any of those aspects can, will, or should affect his story.

Comment: @JBH You probably don't want unimpeded sunlight on the Moon even in your peripheral vision *anyway*, so you're getting no argument from me there. :-)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Armstrong is quoted as saying he never saw stars from the moon. It may be he never had the time to stand in a favorable spot long enough for his eyes to adjust.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Apollo landed in daylight; IIRC near the terminator at the time for thermal control reasons. Thus the sun would be low in the sky (compare the Apollo 12 TV camera mess) and of course you have pretty much the entire visible surface reflecting sunlight. That'd be quite bright, so there's little wonder that the astronauts didn't see stars by the naked eye. Their eyes -- and equipment -- were adapted for sunlight conditions. Hypothetically, laying on one's back in the shadow of the LM with the protective visor out of the way should have been sufficient to see quite some stars.

Comment: We can also compare Apollo 13 passing behind the moon during the circumlunar navigation, which presumably would have had a pretty dark spacecraft interior and thus allowing at least some stars to be seen by the naked eye. (At that point, they had already maneuvered away from the major debris cloud following the oxygen tank explosion, so visual interference from the debris should have been less of a concern.) I'm not sure how much has been written about that, however.

Comment: @JBH when someone points out a factual error in your answer which you agree with, then it would be nice when you edit your answer and correct that error.